# new window/tab event from an <iframe>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an iframe in my website which its content is dynamic and I can't control it.
Is it possible to detect a new-window/tab opened from this iframe using Javascript?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a question you better should ask google. Then you'll find possible solutions, try'n'error and come back if you have a probleme **with a specific programming issue**.

Comment: You can control iframe content with javascript from parent document. Example if i have iframe width id "myIframe" i can get iframe body html like this document.getElementById('myIframe').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

You could do this, but in some weird way :)

If you can edit html on the server where iframe source loads from, place there another iframe (style="width:0px;height:0px;display:none") with src="http://your site/control page". 
This trick will give you DOMdocument control by js on the both side of iframe.